# Set timer on a method of class implementing runnable in main UI thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable

I'm an absolute beginner in android. Currently, I'm trying to make an app that sends output data to arduino via bluetooth. For that purpose, I have created a class as follows.

```
private class SendReceiveBytes implements Runnable {
    private BluetoothSocket btSocket;
    private InputStream inputStream;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    String TAG = "SendReceiveBytes";

    public SendReceiveBytes(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        btSocket = socket;
        try {
            inputStream = btSocket.getInputStream();
            outputStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
        }
        catch (IOException streamError) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error when getting input or output Stream");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // buffer store for the stream.
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        // bytes returned from the stream.
        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = inputStream.read(buffer);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                socketHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error reading from inputStream");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
    public void write(String outputData) {
        try {
            outputStream.write(outputData.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error when writing to outputStream");
        }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            btSocket.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error when closing the btSocket");
        }
    }
}
```

In my OnCreate() method, I'm doing as follows.

```
final SendReceiveBytes sendBytes = new SendReceiveBytes(bluetoothSocket);
final Handler moveHandler = new Handler();
View.OnLongClickListener longClickListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.driveFwd:
                    moveHandler.postDelayed(sendBytes.write("MOVE_FORWARD"), 250);
                    sendBytes.write("MOVE_FORWARD");
                    break;
```

The problem I'm currently having is with the right procedure for invoking method write(). What would be the right way to go on with that?